# ARKit intrinsic differences between portrait and landscape?

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, arkit

I am implementing marker tracking for ARKit using OpenCV (using ARuco) and see good results when doing portrait orientation of the camera, but a slight offset when doing landscape.

ARuco markers on known positions:

[image: ARuco pattern]

Detection in portrait mode works:

[image: Portrait markers]

In landscape orientation, detection is showing an offset:

[image: Landscape markers]

In detail what I am doing:

- For each `ARFrame` do the following:
- Get CVPixelBuffer `height, width, baseaddress` and convert to `cv::Mat`
- Run marker detection and pose estimation (`cv::aruco::detectMarkers`, `cv::aruco::estimatePoseSingleMarkers`) using intrinsic from `ARFrame`.

  - Intrinsic needs to be transposed for ARKit column-major to OpenCV row-major matrix storage.
  - OpenCV `rvec` and `tvec` are converted into a 4x4 transform using `cv::Rodrigues` and then converted from OpenCV to OpenGL coordinate space by `diag(1,-1,-1,1) * transform`
  - Result is converted back from row-major to column-major and is the transform of the marker in camera space.
- Multiplying the transform with the ARCameras transform gives the marker plane in world coordinates, which I visualise as a green rectangle.

My questions:

- Am I missing anything?
- Should `frame.displayTransform` play any part the conversion?
- Why does the intrinsic change when rotating the device? width and height of the pixel buffer do not change.
- Any other ideas?

---

Update 25.07.2017:

- I figured this out! This is a bug from Apple! They messed up the intrinsics between UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft and landscapeRight. If you cache these values and swap them, then everything works great.
- iOS 11 Beta 4 does not change anything
- I am keeping this question open, until it is resolved by Apple (Bug ID 33519315 on Radar).

Update 14.09.2017:

- Apple closed the bug, saying everything is correct. I am not sure that they are correct, but potentially it is really a problem between OpenCV and ARKit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description of your approach and the followup! I'm trying to do something very similar but am stuck at the conversion of rvec & tvec to a transform matrix. Can you be more specific about how you're using the Rodrigues function to create a usable (camera space) transform matrix for the markers? Would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KennyDeriemaeker I am sure this is too late, but I've been working on a demo that does something similar. See ~line 87 in OpenCVWrapper.mm  https://github.com/pukeanddie/aruco-arkit-localizer